# Controlling data between hours using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

My problem is to verify the create time data and current time should be range 8 hour regardless date ?

Thank in advance

> the data type for Create_Date is datetime

```
$time = $this->Ticket->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Ticket.Create_Date >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hour')))));
```

This statement is showing only data from 8 hours not below 8 hours data

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$hr_now = date("H");
$hr_ago = date("H", strtotime('-8 hour'));

$time = $this->Ticket->find('all',
                array('conditions' => array("HOUR(Ticket.Create_Date) BETWEEN $hr_ago AND $hr_now")));
```